# Can you transfer an island to another Switch?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I've got an Animal Crossing Switch, but it's still in the mail so I started playing on my old switch.

Is there a way to transfer an island to another switch?

I guess that since there is 1 island per switch I would guess that transfering the profile doesn't transfer the island. But is there a way to transfer everything of a savefile to another switch? (That, I guess would work)

So is there a way to transfer an Island to another switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to transfer saves. Everything is saved local to the system. Nintendo is working on a system for a one time recovery/transfer in case things go haywire with a console, but New Horizons is not designed to be moved.

The savedata cant even be saved to an SD card.

https://www.newsweek.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-save-files-backup-recover-cloud-online-1488326